# Is there an analog of Tennenbaum's theorem for real arithmetic?

Tags: lo.logic

In other words, does the first order theory of $(\mathbb{R},+,\times,0,1)$ have a computable countable model? What do we know more generally about countable models of real arithmetic?

Comment: The first-order theory of the field of real numbers is the theory of real-closed fields. Its simplest countable model is the field of real algebraic numbers.

Answer (score 13):

Real arithmetic is complete *(trivially, since the theory of any single structure is complete)* and decidable *(by Tarski)*. It's a standard result in computability theory that every complete decidable theory has a computable model: basically, just  run the usual Henkin argument, and note that the only points of possible non-effectiveness are ruled out by the completeness and decidability assumptions.

In the case of real arithmetic we can do better and get *natural* computable models, such as the real algebraic numbers as Andreas Blass observed. But the more general fact above is worth knowing separately.